# Extract part of data from JSON file using python

Tags: python, json, extract, decode

I have been trying to extract only certain data from a JSON file using python.I wanted to create an array from my json which has some entries as below

```
[{"Device Name":"abc", "Device Caps":["a1", "b1", "c1"]},
{"Device Name":"def", "Device Caps":["a2", "b2", "c2"]},
{"Device Name":"ghi", "Device Caps":["a3", "b3", "c3"]},
{"Device Name":"jkl", "Device Caps":["a4", "b4", "c4"]}]
```

I need my output as 
    ["a1","a2","a3","a4"]

Comment: `[item["Device Caps"][0] for item in my_data]`

Comment: So where did you get stuck with this? Note that once parsed, all you have is a list with dictionaries in it. Those are handled the same wherever they came from; this is not really a JSON problem.

Comment: Console throws error while executing this code. Error displayed below.
    `one=[item["Device Caps"][0] for item in data]
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is literally your input file, then the following code will produce the output you want:

```
import json

with open("input.json") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
data = [d["Device Caps"][0] for d in data]

print(data)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\injaleea\Desktop\test1.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = json.load(input_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\injaleea\Desktop\test1.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = json.load(input_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Returned the error below `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\injaleea\Desktop\test1.py", line 13, in <module>data = json.load(input_file)File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load**kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loadreturn _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: From that error message, I infer that what you posted is not your JSON file.

Comment: You were right.My json had some more comment section on top. Is there a way to ignore them ?